Peshat meaning of "help against him" in Biblical Hebrew
Note, this question is NOT about interpretations and commentaries, only about the plain meaning of the verse (Peshat).
The verse says,"אֶעֱשֶׂהּ־לּוֹ עֵזֶר כְּנֶגְדּוֹ". In Biblical Hebrew, עזר means help, rescue, and כנגדו though a singleton, should mean something close to נגד - against, opposing, or facing, like in "וַיִּחַן־שָׁם יִשְׂרָאֵל נֶגֶד הָהָר".
So "rescue against him" - doesn't make sense, it should rather read "עזר לו", or "עזר בשבילו".
How can this phrase be meaningful in its plain reading (Peshat) in Biblical Hebrew?

Slightly related "עזר - rescue or assistance?".

The shoresh נגד appears tons of times in Chumash and in Tanach - Targum Onkelos usually translates it something like קביל and sometimes as קדם but seemingly each time with a meaning of "facing" (but not necessarily "against" in a negative sense).  Sometimes one party facing another party can be with an intent to help.  Sometimes the purpose of facing can be one of opposition where one party intends to harm the other party.

I think the most literal meaning is "opposite". Sometimes it means against, and sometimes it means facing, matching, complementing.

@EraserX Good point, I inserted it into the question, so how about the whole phrase?

@shmosel Good point, I added it also. So how would you translate the whole verse?

What is wrong with Sforno's comment?

@YDJ Just like other commentators, Sforno tries to interpret the word creatively, while my question is about Peshat.

Compare to Tehillim 16:8

שִׁוִּ֬יתִי ה' לְנֶגְדִּ֣י תָמִ֑יד כִּ֥י מִֽ֝ימִינִ֗י בַּל־אֶמּֽוֹט


I have put Hashem לנגדי always, because He is at my right hand I will not
stumble.

Here, לנגדי obviously does not mean "opposing me," but something like "in front of me."  David declares that because Hashem is always before him, in his thoughts, therefore He will offer help and protection and David can be confident that he will not come to harm.
It seems to me that the simple פשט reading of "כנגדו" is similar.  The woman shall be a helper "before him," in his immediate presence rather than at a remote distance.  This fits well with the Divine statement in the same verse that "It is not good for man to be alone."  Because it is not good for him to be alone, he will be provided a helper that will live with him and be constantly with him, ending his state of "aloneness."

Welcome to Mi Yodeya Yehoshua! Looking forward to seeing more from you, with contributions as beautiful as this

Thank you for your kind words.

Like is understand from Rashi's commentary to the Chumash, Peshat also includes proper grammar usage. (His commentary is a tremendous resource for the correct rules of Hebrew grammar.) Your translation of עזר as a verb is incorrect.
In the expression, it is used as a noun. As a noun, it means "assistant" or "complement", meaning a thing that completes and is "complementary to" the subject in the sentence, meaning the individual, the husband.
Similarly, כנגדו is being used as an adjective modifying the subject of the sentence (indicated by the suffix letter ו), which is "him", meaning the man, the husband. (Just to emphasize, it does not say כנגדה, meaning corresponding to her.)
The root, נגד, has several different meanings, which explains why the prefix letter "כ" is also applied. That prefix can have a meaning of "like" or "according to". This means that the type of assistance from the wife varies according to the character and need of the husband.

+1 How would you render the sentence in full then, in summary of your analysis?

@RabbiKaii The full sentence is again, grammatically more detailed. The actual subject is the term האדם, as contrasted with simply אדם. With the specific "ה" it is referring to Adam HaRishon, the progenitor of the species, who was originally comprised of both masculine and feminine in a single being. This parallels the creation of light on day one and then the creation from the single light, two sources of light on day four. That האדם remaining "one" and alone is "לא-טוב". That the טוב (which is gematria 17) is referring to G-d's שם טוב, (אהוה). That is Roshei Treivot: את השמים ואת הארץ.

@RabbiKaii Just to emphasize, since we talked about it before, Ramchal, in Adir B'Marom, in the beginning, mentions this concept of "the potential" for both the future male and female in the single name of G-d, "Elyon", which is referring to צלמו. In Kabbalah, this name is also called the "Supernal Mother". This name gives rise to a child (יהוה) that is without nekudot, meaning transcendent of pronunciation. This "son/child" is also called the Shem HaMeforash, the name which is written one way and pronounced another. This is usually written in Siddurim as: י״י or יאהדונה״י.

@RabbiKaii This is because the concept of "the Point in the Palace" נקודה בהיכל refers to both צלמו (in small sum is gematria 22) which is the small sum of נקודה including the kollel; and also יהוה (gematria 26). That the small sum of נקודה with the letters is also 26. To emphasize, היכל is gematria 65, which is אדני. So יאהדונה״י and צאלדמנ״י are expressions of the same influence, one "above" and one "below", or one "inner" and the other "outer", both grounding to the level of "Action" (עשיה). (Relates to your second email.)

I'm amazed with your knowledge of Jewish esoterics but you still miss my and Rabbi Kaii's question: please provide the closest translation of the whole verse. 2. I never said עזר vas a verb, that's ridiculous. 3. You need to back your assertion that עזר means "assistant" or "complement" anywhere in the Bible.

˜@AlBerko Thank you for the kind words. 1) Your question does not ask for a translation of the entire posuk, only the phrase. That's why I didn't address the posuk. 2) In your question, your English translation usage of עזר is as a verb. Perhaps you aren't being careful about your word usage. 3) Regarding "my assertion" that עזר, as a noun, means "assistant" or "complement", see Jastrow for the Hebrew usage as a noun. Also see the meanings of these English words from Merriam-Webster. If you would like a translation of the whole posuk, please modify your question.

There are multiple valid ways to translate it into English, but the one that makes most sense to me is “a helper facing him,” because facing can mean opposite, against, before, in view, in sight of, conspicuous to, in the presence of, parallel to, from before, open to, known to, etc.
